# Use Quartz for scheduling birthday message in asp.net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz-scheduler

I want to send birthday message to my website users. I use Quartz for scheduling and I wrote some code but I except it work forever but the scheduler work for couple time then it stopped.

I don't know it is IIS server configuration or something else.

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<BirthdaySch>().Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
             .WithIntervalInMinutes(1)
             .RepeatForever())
          .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Start();
    }

    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

asp.net application running thread will be suspend itself while there is no request. quartz will stop also.
first of all you should use windows service or console application to run scheduling service.
build a console application and run it win schedule task, it is best way.
or build windows service, use quartz.net scheduler in service body.